# Is there any significance to the convergence point of recursive interior irregular pentagons?

Tags: geometry

Draw the diagonals in an irregular convex pentagon, forming a new, smaller, irregular pentagon. Repeat until the resulting area is vanishingly small. Does that point have any significant relationship to the original figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two kinds of experimental results (A and B) obtained through numerous experiments (using a Matlab program of my own) and a promising reference (C).

> A) A positive result : the limit process (excepted in the exceptional case of a regular pentagon) has a characteristic feature : the different pentagons are becoming more and more flat giving rise not only to a point but as well to a privilegized direction. It is possible that this direction can be expressed in terms of the coordinates of the inital pentagon.

B) A negative result : I have tried to compare the limit point with two other points, with the aim of conjecturing some properties. These other points are "weighted" centers (see figure):

- $V,$ the center of gravity of vertices (weights $1$ on each vertex), represented by a lozenge.
- $E,$ the center of gravity of weighted edges (the midpoint of each edge reives a weight equal to the length of the corresponding edge), represented by a star.

> The different attempts I have made don't give any plausible property of the limit point of the pentagons vs. the original figure or the other points $V$ and $E$.

---

> C) I just discover (using adequate keywords) that very interesting studies have been done on this issue : see [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02699.pdf)

[image]

Remark : of course, the question could have been settled in an equivalent way for a five-pointed star and its nested iterated internal stars.

Comment: Corollary 1 (iii) page 19 of the cited document states the (observed) total flattening of pentagons.

Comment: see as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram_map and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303457690_On_the_Diagonal_and_Inscribed_Pentagons_of_a_Pentagon

Comment: Thanks, Jean Marie. Your references will be leading me in an interesting direction.

Answer (score 1):

This paper gives the limit you're looking for.

https://academic.oup.com/imrn/advance-article/doi/10.1093/imrn/rny110/5000002

As far as I'm aware it does not have any particular significance other than this property.